# Admob BannerView float over PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: swift, admob, pfquerytableviewcontrolle

I'm trying to get `ADBanner` at the bottom above UITabBarController / float above `UITabBarController` as I'm using `PFQueryTableViewController` I'm getting the ADBanner as a part of `TableViewCell` and the ADBanner is scrollable like the table.
And as I'm using `PFQueryTableViewController` I can't add view to my table . 
as it is scrollable .
The following code I'm using inside `viewDidLoad` method

```
let bannerView: GADBannerView = GADBannerView(adSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)

    bannerView.frame.origin = CGPointMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 49 - 50)
    bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-5819113245629378/9884937047"
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    self.view.addSubview(bannerView)
    bannerView.loadRequest(GADRequest())
```

[image]

Update: This is how I'm adding the containerView.

[image]

Now the containerView is not visible

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PFQueryTableViewController` is a subclass of `UITableViewController`, So if you add any subview to its view whites a tableview will float based on the content of its tableview;

You can try by adding it a view controller instead table view. But in your case it is `PFQueryTableViewController`, My opinion is to add one view controller and add an embedded view controller segue to your `PFQueryTableViewController`.. Then add your banner to your first view controller

**UPDATE**

If you are using storyboard, you can try as follows. Also try  to use auto layout instead of fixed frame.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the support but I previously tried to add view controller but it didn't work also i'm new to the community i have less idea how can I achieve this if possible help me out with some short steps

Comment: I'm at college I'll check it out in evening

Comment: do I have to create new swift file for `UIViewController` for `adbanner` ?

Comment: <UIStoryboardShowSegueTemplate 0x7f8133c30bf0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key containerView.' This the error I'm getting . I used containerView as you told.

Comment: how did you added the container segue?

Comment: Add one container view from object library, remove a view controller which is its default. Then control drag from conainer to your tableview

Comment: Thanks for the support , I used your idea but now on iOS 9.3 it isn't working , when i try to add view to the viewController with containerView , the containerView is automatically removed .

Comment: sorry for the late reply, whats happening exactly?

Comment: i have updated the question . i have uploaded the screenshots you can see above

Comment: you meant removing the container view from storyboard itself? or it not showing in the run time? is it after updating Xcode 7.3 or only for iOS 9.3?